# Error in programming

Tags: vb.net, sapi

```
Imports SpeechLib

Public Class Form1
    Public vox = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
    Private Sub cmdSpeak_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSpeak.Click
        Dim t As String = "Hello , This is a Text"
        Say(t)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Say(ByVal text As String)
        vox.Speak(text,SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync)
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdPause_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPause.Click
        vox.pause()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        vox.AlertBoundary = SVEPhoneme
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am getting an error

> Name 'SVEPhoneme' is not declared.

How and where do I declare it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is SpeechVoiceEvents.SVEPhoneme

This is all a lot easier if you make this code early bound:

```
Public vox as New SpVoice
```

Or better yet, use the .NET wrapper for the sapi, System.Speech assembly.

```
Imports System.Speech.Synthesis

Public Class Form1
    Public vox As New SpeechSynthesizer

    Public Sub Say(ByVal text As String)
        vox.SpeakAsync(text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

SVEPhoneme represents the Phoneme event, which occurs when the engine completes a phoneme while speaking.

Try setting SVEPhoneme to be the integer 64.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720886(v=vs.85).asp

Comment: how do I set it to 64 ?  ... Like this `  Dim SVEPhoneme As Integer = 64`  ?